# How to solve the problem with heating the laptop?

Tags: linux-mint, cpu, temperature, sensors

> The question is:
>
> **How to solve the problem with heating the laptop?**

```
Additional question (optional):
What exactly is the sensors talking about?
```

I had installed Linux Mint and my laptop started to warm up.

How can I deal with the problem, because everything was fine on Windows, but I want to continue using Linux?

I would also like to know what the information in the description of `sensors` means.

What is the meaning of this output from sensors:

```
iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +32.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +57.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +64.0°C
```

PS: The fact that confuses me is that my hands feel hot when I'm using a laptop.

My system's information:

[image]

Comment: What is the focus of your question? You write about the sensor output and a "warm" laptop. Are you trying to figure out how to cool off the laptop, or do you misunderstand the sensor output? It's not obvious (to me) what the "Problem" here is.

Comment: The first one is probably your Wi-Fi card temperature, the second ISA Adapter temperature, third one is ACPI adapter temperature and last one is CPU temperature. It seems high and crit temperatures are Thermal Throttling values even though I think that's a bit high. Your temperatures are fine as stated here.

Comment: I dual-boot between Win7 and Linux Mint. I get less intrusive fan noise with Mint. I believe Linux is doing a smarter job with fan control, but it picks up the cooling when it matters.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry, but I would like to know the answer to both questions. Should I create a separate topic for the second question?

Comment: @JeffSchaller please take a look. Is it ok now?

Comment: @SirMuffington Thanks for the info. But this temperature is practically temperature without any load. At the same time, even when there was a small load on Windows, the laptop was cold. But now laptop feels warm.

Comment: Is there any portion of the sensor output in particular that's confusing?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Does this mean that the use of electricity is more optimized, but from the moment Linux is installed, my fingers will always feel the warm?

Comment: @JeffSchaller The fact that confuses me is that my hands feel hot when i'm using a laptop.

Comment: Thermodynamically, running the system plus a fan has to have a greater total heat output than without. With a fan, most of the heat comes out underneath through the ducting and is dissipated into the room. With less direct cooling, it mainly cools by conduction through the case and keyboard. My CPU is somewhere under the S key, and that end of the keyboard is perhaps 10 deg C warmer than the numeric pad. Processing does not raise my temperature, but just opening a browser gives me a 5 deg jump. Reddit makes my blood boil (but that's just me).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Apparently, the fact is that those who use Linux are hot guys.)